# Capturing number of varying length at the beginning of each line with sed

Tags: sed

I am working with a file that is formatted like so:

```
12345:ABCDEFG

789:HIJK

4963158:LMNOPQRSTUV
```

Each line begins with a number of varying length, followed by a colon, and then followed by a string of letters of varying length. I would like to capture just the numbers at the beginning of each line and put them in a new file, something like this.

```
12345

789

4963158
```

This is as close as I have gotten, but it still prints the entire line instead of just the numbers.

`sed -r 's/([^0-9]+d)(:)([A-Z]+)$/\1/' example.txt >> justnumbers.txt`

What am I doing wrong with the syntax?

Comment: Edit the question and provide sample text as well as the expected output. Do all of lines have the field separators as `:`'s or are there some that have something else? Add this to question and do not post it in the comments.

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Comment: Any particular reason to use `sed`? `cut` or `awk` may be better tools for the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```bash
sed -E 's/([0-9]+):[A-Z]+/\1/' example.txt
```

The `-E` is the same as `-r`, but it's a bit more standard these days.

The issue in your regex is that you are using a negative bracket expression at the beginning (`[^0-9]`), and after that you are matching a literal `d` character.

I also removed the extra capture groups, as they're not needed.

Overall, great effort! You were really close. These are the kind of issues that you get when starting with regexes.

Comment: Much more complicated than `cut -d ":" -f 1 example.txt`.

Comment: `^` is not *negative capture group*, that's to match at the start of the subject. It's needed here. If you also remove the `$` (to match at the end of the subject), the second `+` becomes unnecessary. In effect that code returns the first sequence of one or more digits (well characters in between 0 and 9 which could be anything depending on locale) that is followed by a `:` and a character between `A` and `Z`.

Comment: OP regexp's first capture group was `([^0-9]+d)`. Inside character class brackets `^` _is_ negating the group, so would match anything BUT digits.  But yes it should not be dropped, it should be moved outside the brackets `^([0-9]+)` so that it means start of line.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "negative character class" instead of "negative bracket expression". Updated, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes looking at the problem in a different way can come up with simpler answers.

You looked at it as "I want to keep all the numbers before the :", which is perfectly reasonable.  Another way of looking at it might be "I want to throw away everything from the : to the end".

This leads to

```
s/:.*//
```

as the sed command.

eg

```
$ cat x
12345:ABCDEFG
789:HIJK
4963158:LMNOPQRSTUV

$ sed 's/:.*//' x
12345
789
4963158
```

Comment: That would like `cut -d: -f1` though less reliable in the face of text not encoded as per the user's locale.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yeah, my goal wasn't to provide a most efficient way of solving the ask but to demonstrate that looking at the same problem in different ways can lead to different solutions.

Answer (score 6):

If the point is to return what's left of the first `:` on each line, then it's just a matter of:

```
<your-file cut -d: -f1
```

Adding the `-s` option would skip the lines that don't contain any `:`.

To return what's left of the `:` only on lines that consist of 1 or more ASCII digits followed by a `:` followed by one or more ASCII uppercase letters, and discard any line that doesn't match that pattern, that's where you would use `sed` / `awk` / `perl`:

```
<your-file sed -n '^\([0123456789]\{1,\}\):[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]\{1,\}$/\1/p'
```

Or:

```
<your-file LC_ALL=C sed -n 's/^\([0-9]\{1,\}\):[A-Z]\{1,\}$/\1/p'
```

(the `C` locale being the only one where those `[0-9]`, `[A-Z]` ranges are guaranteed to be equivalent to the explicit sets from the first command).

Or if your `sed` supports the `-E` option for `E`xtended regular expressions (extended as in being from the 70s instead of the 60s¹ though `sed` implementations didn't start adding support for them until the late 90s):

```
<your-file LC_ALL=C sed -nE 's/^([0-9]+):[A-Z]+$/\1/p'
```

Or using `perl` (with its regexps from the 80s¹):

```
<your-file perl -lne 'print $1 if /^(\d+):[A-Z]+$/'
```

`pcregrep` is a `grep` implementation that uses `perl`-like regexps and supports a `-o<n>` to output the `n`<sup>th</sup> capture group:

```
<your-file pcregrep -xo1 '(\d+):[A-Z]+'
```

Some `grep` implementations also have a `-o` option but only to output the whole match but some support `-P` to use perl-like regexps where you can use look-around operators to check for things without them being included in the match:

```
<your-file grep -Po '^(\d+)(?=:[A-Z]+$)'
```

Which matches a sequence of 1 or more digits at the start of the line, provided it's followed (`(?=...)` look-ahead operator) by `:`, 1 or more `[A-Z]`s (not locale-sensitive in perl regexps, so the `LC_ALL=C` is not necessary) followed by the end of the line.

---

<sup>¹ Though to be fair, they've all evolved since then, especially for the perl ones. EREs from the late 70s added `+`, `?` and `|` (and more importantly a new algorithm to do the matching) but lost `\x` back-references. `\{min,max\}` was added to BRE later in the 80s (so could do the equivalent of `+` and `?`), `{min,max}` was added to ERE again later, but not always as that broke backward compatibility. POSIX have introduced some `[[:class:]]`, `[[=x=]]`, `[[.x.]]` (for better or worth). Some implementations of both BRE/ERE have non-standard extensions, including some from `perl` such as `\d` or `*?`.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -pe 's/^ (\d+) \: .* $/$0/;'  file

#OR

~$ raku -pe 's/^ \d+ <( \: .* $//;'  file
```

If you look at a number of different Regex implementations, it helps you spot common themes. For both Perl and Raku, the `-pe` command line flags give `sed`-like behavior that runs code over each line and autoprints.

The first Raku example above captures `^` start-of-string `\d+` digits (one-or-more), which are followed by a `:` colon (backslash escaped) and `.*` any-character zero-or-more times, up to the `$` end-of-string (i.e. line). Raku captures start from `$0` and digits captured into `$0` are used in the replacement half of `s///` to replace the entirety of the match object (which is the whole line).

The second Raku example above takes the opposite approach: it matches `^` start-of-string `\d+` digits (one-or-more), which are followed by a `:` colon (backslash escaped) and `.*` any-character zero-or-more times, up to the `$` end-of-string (i.e. line). However the `<(` "capture marker" tell Raku's regex engine to drop the preceding `\d+` digits from the match object, and only retain what comes after. In the replacement everything remaining in the match object is deleted (replaced with nothing), thus only the `\d+` start-of-string digits remain.

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Capture_markers:_%3C(_)%3E
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org